# What's better? Return a list of object pointers? or Return a pointer to list of objects?

Tags: c++, performance, optimization, rvo

I have a code that read Products from database and return them as a list.

```
std::list<Product> findAll() {...}
```

The code above (CRUD) is part of a library (third party library).
Client code get the list and pass it over 3 layers (MVC).
I know this process copy the list on every call.

I want to improve this process and the questions are: Getting the list

- Should I create a list of Product pointers and return it.`std::list<Product*> products;`
- Or should I create a pointer to list of Products and return it. `std::list<Product> *productsPtr;`

What's more efficient? Return a list of Product pointers or return a pointer to a list.
I know that modern compilers have **RVO**. **How can I use that feature?**. Because, I'm using clang-v5.0.0 and sending outputs to screen I saw that products are created and destroyed every time (copy).

And some questions more. What's better?:

- A library should return a list of Product objects (current state)? or a list of Product pointers (smart pointers) or receive a list reference as parameter?
- Product class must implement **move constructors** to guarantee RVO?

---

More info.

- Product class has default constructor. Its info (id, name, price, etc.) are filled by setters and getters.
- The list is mainly used to be shown on tables. However the list must pass from library to Model, then to Controller and finally to View. The view allows add, update and delete Products. That's the reason of my question.
- I like the idea to use `std::vector` because improve data access.

But my principal doubts here is: return a container (list, vector, etc) of Plain Objects or pointers or a pointer to container?.

Comment: What is `Product` exactly? Does it have non-trivial copy constructor?

Comment: Who is the owner of the `Product`s? How is this list of `Product`s going to be used? What's the access pattern?

Comment: Side note: Are you sure you want to use a `std::list` here? `list`s can be surprisingly slow . You might get all the performance you need you want from using a `std::vector` instead.

Comment: I would usually find that returning a plain container of objects to be the best solution, unless your profiler tells you doing that is what's ruining performance. And btw; a list is probably the most *inefficient* datastructure you could use. *My* first change would probably be to use a `std::vector` instead.

Comment: If `findAll` is something like `std::list<Product> rval; add stuff to rval; return rval;` returning a pointer is a bad idea. It's out of scope,  so you'll have to dynamically allocate. As soon as you dynamically allocate, someone is going to leak it. You can fix that problem by returning a `std::unique_ptr<std::list<Product>>` but that's a lot of work for you, the user, and the program.

Comment: If performance is what you're interested in, then surely you have measured the speed. Which one of your options was fastest?

Comment: New info added to question.

Comment: In general library containers are at their absolute best when they directly contain data rather than pointers to data. This is particularly noticeable with `vector` where contiguity of the data allows the CPU to take full advantage of cache. However, if you have to copy items into the container and the copy is more expensive than the extra pointer-chasing and cache unfriendliness, the pointer becomes more attractive. You'll find that out while profiling.

Comment: If the algorithm using the returned container modifies the items in the container and expects the originals to reflect the changes, copies cannot do what you want. You'll have to use pointers or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using C++11 or higher (which you should), returning `std::list<Product>` is the better option, since no copy will take place.

If you are using an older C++, you should probably pass an out parameter `std::list<Product>&`. Using a list of pointers is neither effecient nor comfortable, and it will invoke the copy on the pointers as well - it might be better than copying the whole product but it is still an unnecessary copy.

By the way, if effeciency bothers you, you should probably use a vector (unless you are sure you don't need to).

About RVO (C++11 or higher) - if you return a non-const object from a function, it uses its move constructor instead of copying the data. 
There is a concept of copy elision - if you return a newly-constructed

For example:

```cpp
return std::vector{1,2,3,4,5};
```

The compiler will construct the object in-place for the returned value.

**Note** - copy elision is part of the standard*emphasized text* as for C++17.